# How to distinguish in-code javascript from client ones

Tags: javascript, client-side

I know javascript is a client-side language but I'm trying to find an answer if somehow the javascript code embedded in the actual code can differ from the one which is run on the console. Let me explain it with an example:

I want to create an analytics tool like MixPanel does. MixPanel takes all the tracking with a javascript function `mixpanel.track("string etc")`. Assume I have a website called somehow.com. In the code of somehow.com, I'm using `mixpanel.track("")` function a lot to track my pages through mixpanel. But when I open the console (from Chrome let's say) when the somehow.com is open in the browser and type `mixpanel.track("whatssup")`, this tracking would also be valid and mixpanel tracks this one also. That is unacceptable for my case but I passionately want to use javascript since no other library would be necessary if javascript would be used. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can't detect whether JavaScript was ran from the console or not.

Comment: And even if you could, a user can just as easily insert a script into the page itself.

Comment: In the long run this will be in the noise and should have a negligible impact on your tracking statistics. Don't waste time worrying about it.

Comment: Not reliably. You could tinker around with having the code send a "hidden" key, but that key wouldn't be so hidden that it couldn't be discovered using developer tools.

Comment: What is the attack model you are hoping to defend against? Why is the web working the way it always works "unacceptable"?

Answer (score 2):

Client side code is not secure and you cannot control how it is modified or run.  It's client-side and the client can do anything it darn well pleases (with a properly skilled hacker).  Security or protection from abuse always has to be done server-side.

For us to offer more help, you would have to describe more about what you're really trying to protect against.